# Laravel eloquent ORM beginner

Tags: orm, laravel, eloquent

I try to make a simple request.
Suppose logged user have "projects".
And suppose "projects" have many "comment".

I try to get all project from user with all comment by project.

I have table called "users", "projects", "comments".
Users is managed by Sentry.

I have two models : Project and Comment :

```
class Project extends Eloquent { ... }
class Comment extends Eloquent { ... }
```

In my Model "Project" I have this :

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Comment');
}
```

In my Controllers I have this

```
$projects = Project::comments()->paginate(10);
```

And ... doesn't work.
In a best way I want something like this

```
$projects = Project::comments()->where('projects.account_id', '=', Sentry::getUser()->id)->paginate(10);
```

Can you help me?

### edit

Ok, now, I modified models like this

User model :

```
public function project()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Project');
}
```

Projects model :

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User');
}
```

Comments model :

```
public function project()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Projects');
}
```

And in my controller :

```
$projects = User::with( array('project', 'project.comments') )->find( Sentry::getUser()->id );
```

and Laravel say "Trying to get property of non-object" in my blade loop :

```
@foreach ($projects as $project)
    {{ $project->slug }}
@endforeach
```

Almost ..

### edit

Ok works fine. I modified my view and it's ok.
THANKS ALL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all projects from a user, with all comments on that project you need to do this:`User::with(array('projects', 'projects.comments'))->find(Sentry::getUser()->id);`

That will grab the current user, eager loaded with all projects and project comments associated with that project!

Comment: Doesn't work for me, Laravel say : Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::hasManyThrough()

Comment: Projects haven't user_id but account_id. It's for that ?

Comment: Your relationships are not set up properly then.  You need to ensure the eloquent relationships are set up properly first.

Comment: This looks more like the laravel version is incorrect for what he's trying to do. `hasManyThrough` is new to Laravel 4.1, are you sure you are using 4.1?

Comment: Yes, sure.
@bgallagh3r I have fixed that, now projects have user_id and no effect. crap.